# Get current screen name in POS Odoo

Tags: odoo-10, point-of-sale

How do I get current screen name in POS (Odoo 10)?
I've seen get_current_screen function, but can't use it properly. Please, define me proper way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to require below js class.

```
var gui = require('point_of_sale.gui');
```

Then you can get the current screen using.

```
alert(gui.current_screen);
```